# Where I can see the system log of jenkins

Tags: jenkins, logfile

The Jenkins that we use for ETL automation stopped its service and then  restarted it using command prompt. But I wanted to investigate about the reason that caused it to stop. But in System log file of Jenkins I can see only today's log. How can I see log of previous days. Please help.

Answer (score 13):

If you are using a linux machine logs will be in **/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log** unless you have set customized location. If you have set any logrotate it will be archived and you might require to unzip and check those to see previous logs.

Take a look at this [documentation](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Logging) for more info

Comment: Thanking you for your comment. I am using windows and i found this  %JENKINS_HOME%/jenkins.out and %JENKINS_HOME%/jenkins.err . Is this a command or path?. How I can use this to get the log?

Comment: No i am not. I just got the %JENKINS_HOME%/jenkins.out  command from the documentation given by you. but how can i use it as a command? please help.

Comment: Open your command prompt and check what is the value of JENKINS_HOME. Simply typing it in dos prompt will display value I think (I am not a windows person :) )

Comment: Once you get that you can simply cd or directly cd to $JENKINS_HOME will also work I think. You should be able to see logs. You would be also be able to check variable from control panel- system-advanced system settings-environment variables

Comment: If you are unable to find %JENKINS_HOME% go to Manage Jenkins > Configure sytem. There can find Jenkins home path(Should be the first field) Thats the Jenkins Home directory, You can locate the logs under that.

Comment: I got the .err file and .out file but It doesn't have log details. .out file is empty and .err file is last updated long before. And in jenkins.xml i cannot see any config related to log.

Comment: Check if you have set any custom log location instead of default one

Answer (score 2):

I found logs from the web panel
https://jenkins.mycompany.com.ua/log/all